Help me to get the tex code of this

Help me to get the tex code of this

Welcome. // Kindly read the tutorials in https://tikz.dev/ .

Welcome to TeX.SX! On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a minimal working example (MWE): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

This site is not meant to be a human-powered image-to-TeX conversion tool and therefore, you should show what you tried so far in order to receive help with your specific problem.
But you could try with this solution using the l3draw package:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \draw_begin:
        \draw_path_moveto:n { 0cm , 0cm }
        \draw_path_lineto:n { 2cm , .25cm }
        \draw_path_lineto:n { -2.5cm , -5cm }
        \draw_path_lineto:n { 2.5cm , -4.25cm }
        \draw_path_close:
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
        \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin { M }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_coffin { l } { vc } { 2.25cm , .25cm }
        \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin { N }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_coffin { r } { vc } { -.25cm , 0cm }
        \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin { A }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_coffin { l } { vc } { 1cm , -1.25cm }
        \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin { B }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_coffin { r } { vc } { -2.75cm , -5cm }
        \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin { C }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_coffin { l } { vc } { 2.75cm , -4.25cm }
    \draw_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}


